# SQL Server - Error Connecting to the Database

Tags: sql-server

I had to reformat my machine. I had a database working on my previous installation. I also have a web application that connects to this database on the same machine. When I attempt to access the database through the web application, I receive an error. So then I attempted to manually connect to the database.

When I attempt to login with the credentials that my web application is using, I receive the following error:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred  
during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is 
on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
```

I ensured that the user/pass was created. What am I missing? I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some of the solutions for `Error: 233` here on the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/b9864938-3b9d-46ed-913c-1014d93738d5